# Finding highest rectangle's average value in a 2d array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, optimization

I need to find out which rectangle in a given 2d array has the highest average value. Obviously the answer is 1x1 rectangle containing only the highest valued cell. However, only rectangles whose both sides equal or exceed a given value are valid and should be considered.

The problem is technically easy to solve:

```
def highest_average(array, minsize):
    highest = -1, -1, -1, -1, -float("inf")
    width, height = len(array[0]), len(array)
    for rowstart in range(height-minsize):
        for colstart in range(width-minsize):
            for rowend in range(rowstart+minsize, height):
                for colend in range(colstart+minsize, width):
                    val = sum(
                        sum(array[row][col] for row in range(rowstart, rowend+1)) for col in range(colstart, colend+1)
                    )/((rowend-rowstart)*(colend-colstart))
                    if val > highest[4]:
                        highest = rowstart, colstart, rowend, colend, val
    return highest

# Random-valued 16x16 array
array = [[random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(16)] for _ in range(16)]
for row in array:
    print(" ".join("{:3d}".format(f) for f in row))

# Calculated average with min rectangle size 4x4
print(highest_average(array, 4))
```

but this is only usable for small arrays. Running this function with large array (100x100 or more), and a `minsize` of, say, 10 would take hours to return.

Are there any methods I can use to reduce the runtime? Obviously I'm not looking for tricks to reduce time by .1%, I need to substantially increase the speed of execution.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @GKS In the end I worked around it, avoiding the problem itself.